# Ruby: Make a call from browser using Twilio

Tags: ruby, twilio, twilio-click-to-call

I want to call from my browser to customer phone number using Twilio. I am using [toturial](https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/ruby/client/hangup) of Twilio. I have already an account that I am using for sending sms to my users. Now I want to make phone calls too. This is the code that I am using at my controller

```
account_sid = "My Twilio account SID"
auth_token = "My Twilio auth"
sender = "My Twilio from number"
capability = Twilio::Util::Capability.new account_sid, auth_token
capability.allow_client_outgoing "My Twilio Twiml app sid"
#capability.allow_client_incoming "jenny"
@token = capability.generate
```

And this is the javascript code

```
  Twilio.Device.setup("<%= @token %>", {debug: true});

  Twilio.Device.ready(function (device) {
      $("#log").text("Ready");
  });

  Twilio.Device.error(function (error) {
      $("#log").text("Error: " + error.message);
  });

  Twilio.Device.connect(function (conn) {
      $("#log").text("Successfully established call");
  });

  Twilio.Device.disconnect(function (conn) {
      $("#log").text("Call ended");
  });

  Twilio.Device.incoming(function (conn) {
      $("#log").text("Incoming connection from " + conn.parameters.From);
      // accept the incoming connection and start two-way audio
      conn.accept();
  });

  function call() {
      // get the phone number to connect the call to
      params = {"PhoneNumber": $("#number").val()};
      Twilio.Device.connect(params);
  }

  function hangup() {
      Twilio.Device.disconnectAll();
  }
```

But when I try to load my page, it gives me `Error: No valid account`. I have double checked my credentials and same credentials are successfully sending sms but here it is creating problem. Can any one guide me what Am I doing wrong?

I am doing it on localhost

Comment: Twilio developer evangelist here. Where do you get the "no valid account" error message? In the controller or the JavaScript? Everything looks good to me at the moment.

Comment: Its in JavaScript. Its log in browser.

Comment: What do you get if you try to log the `@token` in the browser?

Comment: It is some long string...

Comment: Huh, can you email me at philnash@twilio.com with any more details that you can't share here?

Comment: what information you actually in need of? Let me tell and I will send you

Comment: Uh, actually, I can't think of anything else you can give me, would be better to take this out of SO though.

Comment: And how you want me to do it?

Comment: Well, you can either email me, on the above email address and I'll try to debug with you, or you could email help@twilio.com and they will get you sorted too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Megan from Twilio here. You mention you're on localhost. You would need to make your URL publicly accessible. If you're not ready for production, [testing with something](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2015/09/6-awesome-reasons-to-use-ngrok-when-testing-webhooks.html) like [Ngrok](https://ngrok.com) will allow you to tunnel your localhost to a publicly available URL.

Comment: Hi Megan, Thank you for your response